# Formatting number in xslt

Tags: xslt, numbers

I am trying to format a number in XSLT, but I always get `NaN` as a result.

Original example number is: `1 321.94`

Code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(string(.)), '### ##0,00', 'format1')"/>
```

Seems like `number(string(.))` doesn't work. How can I remove the space from the original number to cope with `NaN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `translate()` should work for both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0. You could also use `replace()` in 2.0.

Here's an example of `translate()` (broken up into multiple lines for readability):

```
<xsl:value-of 
  select="format-number(
  number(translate(.,' ','')),
  '### ##0,00','format1')"/>
```